# Display javascript input text in JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my HTML code,

```js
$(".slide").each(function() {
  var a = $(this).find(".input-field"),
    b = $(this).find("a");

  b.click(function() {
    console.log(a.value());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" class="step-form d-flex">
  <div class="slide">
    <h3>Enter your code1</h3>
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="ZIP CODE">

    <p><a href="#" class="btn-start">Start now!</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="slide">
    <h3>Enter your code2</h3>
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="ZIP CODE">

    <p><a href="#" class="btn-start">Start now!</a></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'd like to display the entered text on the input when the button was click.

I've been try this code. but I always results to undefined;

Comment: Your question is unclear.. On what input you want to display the entered text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be **.val()** not **.value()**

```
$(".slide").each(function() {
  var a = $(this).find(".input-field"),
  b = $(this).find("a");
  b.click(function() {
    console.log(a.val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you need to use `val()` instead of `value()` ([API](http://api.jquery.com/val/)):

```js
$(".slide").each(function() {
  var a = $(this).find(".input-field"),
    b = $(this).find("a");

  b.click(function() {
    console.log(a.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" class="step-form d-flex">
  <div class="slide">
    <h3>Enter your code1</h3>
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="ZIP CODE">

    <p><a href="#" class="btn-start">Start now!</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="slide">
    <h3>Enter your code2</h3>
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="ZIP CODE">

    <p><a href="#" class="btn-start">Start now!</a></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```js
$(".btn-start").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).closest('.slide').find('.input-field').val());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" class="step-form d-flex">
  <div class="slide">
    <h3>Enter your code1</h3>
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="ZIP CODE">

    <p><a href="#" class="btn-start">Start now!</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="slide">
    <h3>Enter your code2</h3>
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="ZIP CODE">

    <p><a href="#" class="btn-start">Start now!</a></p>
  </div>
</form>
```